# Need an Effective Algorithim to Move Game Piece According to Specifications (Game: Janggi)

Tags: python, algorithm, class, oop

I'm building the back-end in Python for a Korean chess-like game called Janggi.

Here's some basic rules: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Janggi

There is a couple of pieces that are a bit challenging to build I'm finding... Namely the Horse and Elephant piece.

They have the same kind of problem, so I'll just focus on the Horse Piece.

Essentially, the Horse piece moves one step orthogonally then one step diagonally outward, with no jumping. The way I have the `is_legal_move()` method set up it should return True or False if the move is possible. (This method is piece specific. Other methods in other classes make sure the general legal moves are observed).

However, I currently don't account for the "not jumping" rule. I essentially just have a list of legal transposed coordinates. But if there was a piece in between the to and from coordinates, it doesn't detect that problem.

Trying to think how I can account for the spaces the Horse would have to "walk" in between the from coordinates and the to coordinates...

This is my current iteration.

```
class Horse(GamePiece):
    """
    Represents Horse game piece, inherits from Game Piece class
    """

    def __init__(self, _player_piece_color):
        """

        """
        super().__init__(_player_piece_color)
        self._moves = [(-1, -2), (-1, 2), (-2, -1),
                    (-2, 1), (0, 0), (1, -2), 
                    (1, 2), (2, -1), (2, 1)]
    
    def is_legal_move(self, x_from, y_from, x_to, y_to):
        """
        checks that Horse piece can make attempted move
        returns True if legal, False otherwise
        """
        
        diff = (x_to - x_from, y_to - y_from)
        return diff in self._moves
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a `self._jumps` dictionary that takes a `diff` as a key and returns the intervening position that nothing can be in.

You also need to add an argument to `is_legal_move` for the board so that you can check the condition.

And yes, you need to add that argument to the same method for other pieces.  But they can just ignore it.

Comment: That makes sense, I'll give it a shot. What about the pieces also inheriting from the board so they can access it directly? Or will that get messy with all the instantiation?

Comment: @Hofbr That falls under "prefer composition over inheritance".  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance for more.  But beyond the general principle, if the piece knows about the board and the board about the piece, you've created a circular pattern that breaks reference counting.  Sure, eventually the garbage collector will collect garbage, but why make it do extra work to find it?

Comment: Yes that sounds reasonable... The board actually is a collection of empty spaces and instances of GamePiece Child Objects. Is there a way for me to call the Board class variables from the Piece Classes and ensure I'm referencing the same instance?

For instance, if I wanted to view other pieces on the current state of the board that I'm playing on, can one of Piece classes check with the board? Is the only way to pass the board down as an argument in a Piece method?